# How to add fixed navbar in react-router-dom v6.4.5

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

As, I'm migrating my routes from old version to v6.4.5.But is not showing me Home & Auth component. Is there any way to fix it so that i can make it working.

```
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/Home/Home";
import Auth from "./components/Auth/Auth";
import { createBrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
      <Navbar />
    </Container>
  );
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
  
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/home",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/auth",
        element: <Auth />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `<App>` as the path `"/"` by default (it's not specified in [the doc](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)), you need to remove it from your children routes:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/"
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "home",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "auth",
        element: <Auth />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Comment: Nothing is showing instead it is showing me warning in console. Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check your code at index.js:18.

Comment: @SohaibButt Well, it must be an error in your component.

Comment: Yes i fixed it. It is working fine.

Comment: @SohaibButt Out of curiosity, do you need to set explicitly the path for `<App>` or it has a default value?

Comment: It works by adding the outlet   
<>
<Container maxWidth="lg">
      <Navbar />
    </Container>
<Outlet/>
</>